# I have 0 bytes of free disk space and I can't log in. What can I do?

Tags: login

I was running an overwritting of free disk space with "sfill" and while the process was going there was a blackout and my computer turned off. Now when I try to log in I get a message saying I either don't have enough free space or don't have permission to access. I already tried deleting several files at /home/user and also the content inside /tmp but non have worked, and when I run "df" I see 100% used space even after deleting some stuff.